# What is the equivalent of append or add to push to front?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I am in a programming context. I am writing a commit message and I am struggling to find a word for the following action: In a list of items, I added some elements at the front of the list. We are used to *append* or *add* to push to the back of the list. In this case I would have written:

> fix(scope): *append* missing element to list X

but in my case, I don't know which verb to use.

> fix(scope): __*{verb}*__ missing element to list X

So, what is the equivalent of *append* or *add* to push onto the front of something?

Comment: Is it an English language question or a coding question? It does not have to be one word for English language. For coding there will be language specific syntax.

Comment: It is an english question in a coding context. It is for human and not for computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want ***[prepend](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prepend)***:

> add (something) to the beginning of something else.
>   *"you forgot to prepend ‘I personally believe’ to the statements you are making"*
>
> Computing
>       attach (a piece of data) to the beginning of another.
>   *"in this case, you must prepend the server name to the database name, separated by a period"*
>
> <sub>*definition from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prepend), via Google*</sub>